# How can I reify a Symbol in order to pass it into runtime?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros

Macro contexts in Scala come with two handy methods: `reifyType` and `reifyTree` which essentially generate code that, when executed at runtime, will return the `Type` or `Tree` being reified.

I wonder if there is some way to achieve something similar with `Symbol`s - some kind of `reifySymbol` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We didn't implement `reifySymbol` yet, but it might be decently emulated by wrapping a symbol in an `Ident` and then reifying the resulting tree. Pull requests are welcome as well :)

Comment: Now that I think of it, will the trick with `Ident` work for all symbols (e.g. `MethodSymbol`s)?